# Codeigniter Not Displaying Correct $config

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My config item is not working correctly, for some reason. Won't display correct theme. It shows the default theme but should display the codeigniter theme.

**The default theme is back up so if file not exist it shows default.**

**I also am getting an array error**

1: Should display current theme.

Config file template.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
// Template Change
$config['config_template'] = 'codeigniter';
?>
```

Controller Welcome.php

```
public function index() {
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/header', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

    if (file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message', $data)) {
       $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message';
    } else {
    $this->load->view('default/template/common/welcome_message', $data);
}
```

2: Issue with file exists

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: file_exists() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given
Filename: controllers/welcome.php
Line Number: 9**

Comment: Well, the error with file_exists is self explanatory, you are passing 2 parameters into a method that only accepts one parameter. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php.

Comment: I need the 2 lots of $data though because it is for if file exists and if does not will load $this->load->view('default/template/common/welcome_message', $data); It only display my default theme should display my codeigniter

Comment: You simply **CAN NOT** pass two items into a method which only accepts one parameter. Your line `$this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message';` makes absolutely no sense. You are just creating a string, then doing nothing with it. I suggest you research codeigniter some more.

Comment: @mituw16 How would you do it. It is so long as I can get the default theme as a fall back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea what you're using for the themes, but from what I see:

- `$this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message';`

This line makes absolutely no sense. It's the same if you just write

```
'something/template/common/welcome_message';
```

I'm pretty sure you want to do this instead:

```
$this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') .'/template/common/welcome_message', $data);
```

- `file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message', $data)`

Here you have 1 redundant parameter. As the error says, `file_exists()` accepts 1 argument, and you have 2 (the second is `$data`) - remove it and the error should go away. I guess you wanted to put it in the next line inside `$this->load->view`

**Edit:** And to be clear, here's the complete code you should use.

```
public function index() {
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/header', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

    if (file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message')) {
       $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('default/template/common/welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: The config item get the theme folders name. I need it to also work saying if file exists it will display it. Else use the default view as shown above. It did work before I added the if else

Comment: @user3475662 Check my answer again - I've added complete code for you to try out. It will be good however to get some knowledge on the language basics before you try to write code with a framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the "template.php", something like this
   `$this->config->load('template');`

So your code (Controller Welcome.php) will be:

```
public function index() {
    $this->config->load('template');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/header', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

    if (file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message', $data)) {
       $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/welcome_message';
    } else {
       $this->load->view('default/template/common/welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have auto loaded it

Comment: That's right. I cannot just set a variable somewhere and expect it to be available through all your application;

Comment: @user3475662 do  echo "<pre>";print_r($this->config);exit; and check if template.php is load? if it is loaded then check if you can find "config_template" in the output of print_r